# Is it possible to hide a folder from a specific user?

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, show-hide

I have a situation here.
I want to hide a folder from a specific user in Windows Seven. 
This is not just a simple hide. I want to hide the folder from other 'Standard Users' (not administrator) logging into the system in such a way that they don't even know the existence of the folder.

I found that if a folder is hidden by administrator, then if the standard user enables 'Show hidden files and folders', the folder becomes visible. Well, they cannot access the contents due to permissions, that is fine.

But what I want is even if the standard user enables 'Show hidden files and folders' windows will not show the hidden folder to them. I want the folder to be seen by administrator only.

This does not necessarily mean that I have to 'hide' it.
I want to setup something which will allow only the administrator to know that the folder exists.

Is this at all possible?
If its possible please share the knowledge on how it is possible.

Thanks in advance.
Nirmalya